# Complexity of a neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I need to measure the performance of any query.

for example :

```
MATCH (n:StateNode)-[r:has_city]->(n1:CityNode)
WHERE n.shortName IN {0} and n1.name IN {1} 
WITH n1
Match (aa:ActiveStatusNode{isActive:toBoolean('true')})--(n2:PannaResume)-[r1:has_location]->(n1)
WHERE (n2.firstName="master") OR (n2.lastName="grew" )
WITH n2  
MATCH (o:PannaResumeOrganizationNode)<-[h:has_organization]-(n2)-[r2:has_skill]->(n3:Skill)
WHERE (0={3} OR o.organizationId={3}) AND (0={4} OR n3.name IN {2} OR n3.name IN {5}) 
WITH size(collect(n3)) as count, n2 
MATCH (n2) where (0={4} OR count={4}) 
RETURN DISTINCT n2
```

I have tried **profile & explain** clauses but they only return number of db hits. Is it possible to get big notations for a neo4j query ie cn we measure performance in terms of big O notations ? Are there any other ways to check query performance apart from using **profile & explain** ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot convert a Cypher to Big O notation.

Cypher does not describe how to fetch information, only what kind of information you want to return. It is up to the Cypher planner in the Neo4j database to convert a Cypher into an executable query (using heuristics about what info it has to find, what indexes are available to it, and internal statistics about the dataset being queried. So simply changing the state of the database can change the complexity of a Cypher.)

A very simple example of this is the Cypher `Cypher 3.1 MATCH (a{id:1})-[*0..25]->(b) RETURN DISTINCT b`. Using a fairly average connected graph with cycles, running against Neo4j 3.1.1 will time out for being too complex (Because the planner tries to find all paths, even though it doesn't need that redundant information), while Neo4j 3.2.3 will return very quickly (Because the Planner recognizes it only needs to do a graph scan like depth first search to find all connected nodes).

---

Side note, you can argue for BIG O notation on the return results. For example `MATCH (a), (b)` must have a minimum complexity of n^2 because the result is a Cartesian product, and execution can't be less complex then the answer. This understanding of how complexity affects row counts can help you write Cyphers that reduce the amount of work the Planner ends up planning.

For example, using `WITH COLLECT(n) as data MATCH (c:M)` to reduce the number of rows the Planner ends up doing work against before the next part of a Cypher from nm (first match count times second match count) to m (1 times second match count).

However, since Cypher makes no promises about how data is found, there is no way to guarantee the complexity of the execution. We can only try to write Cyphers that are more likely to get an optimal execution plan, and use EXPLAIN/PROFILE to evaluate if the planner is able to find a relatively optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The PROFILE results show you how the neo4j server actually plans to process your Cypher query. You need to analyze the execution plan revealed by the PROFILE results to get the big O complexity. There are no tools to do that that I am aware of (although it would be a great idea for someone to create one).

*You should also be aware that the execution plan for a query can change over time as the characteristics of the DB change, and also when changing to a different version of neo4j.*

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of this is sort is readily available.  But it can be derived/approximated with some additional effort.

On profiling a query, we get a list of functions that neo4j will run to achieve the desired result. 
Each of this function will be associated with the worst to best case complexities in theory. And some of them will run in parallel too. This will impact runtimes, depending on the cores that your server has.

For example match (a:A) match (a:B) results in Cartesian product. And this will be of O(count(a)*count(b))

Similarly each function of in your query-plan does have such time complexities.

So aggregations of this individual time complexities of these functions will  give you an overall approximation of time-complexity of the query.

But this will change from time to time with each version of neo4j since they community can always change the implantation of a query or to  achieve better runtimes / structural changes / parallelization/ less usage of ram.

If what you are looking for is an indication of the optimization of neo4j query db-hits is a good indicator.